# Counting Positive Integers with a Given Number of Divisors

Tags: c, algorithm, number-theory

basically what i was trying to  do is insert an integer k that represents the number of divisors and then finding all the numbers that have k divisors from 1-100000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k, x = 1, y = 100000, divisor, count;

    printf("Enter the target number of divisors:\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);



    for (divisor = 0; divisor <= 1; divisor++)
        if (x % divisor == 0 && y % divisor == 0)
           count++;

    printf("There are %d numbers between 1 and 100000 inclusive which have exactly %d   divisors\n", k, divisor);

    return 0;
}
```

However I can't seem to be able to do it, please do help me as I'm fairly new to the programming scene and haven't found an answer elsewhere.

Comment: What is the meaning that was input the value of `k`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the number of divisors of the integers we are searching for?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev It will be replaced without being used.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yeah, but then assigns k = 1, so there is no reason to read k.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY aaahh you mean in the code... I thought you meant the question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

There is a theorem that states if you have the [canonical representation of an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer) being a<sub>1</sub><sup>b<sub>1</sub></sup> * a<sub>2</sub><sup>b<sub>2</sub></sup> ... a<sub>n</sub><sup>b<sub>n</sub></sup> then the number of divisors of this integer is (b<sub>1</sub> + 1) * (b<sub>2</sub> + 1) ... (b<sub>n</sub> + 1).

Now that you have this theorem, you can modify slightly Eratosthenes's sieve to get all integers up to 100 000 in canonical form.

Here is some code that does what I mean by modified erathosthenes's sieve.

```
const int size = 100000;
int devs[size + 1];
void compute_devs() {
  for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i) {
    devs[i] = (i%2 == 0) ? 2 : 1;
  }

  int o = sqrt(size);    
  for (int i = 3; i <= size; i += 2) {
    if (devs[i] != 1) {
      continue;
    }
    devs[i] = i;
    if (i <= o) {
      for (int j = i * i; j < size; j += 2 * i) {
        devs[j] = i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After calling `compute_devs` the value of devs will store the value of the greatest prime divisor of each number up to size. I will leave the rest of the task to you, but having this array it becomes pretty straight forward.