# C-amount of numbers that have x number of factors within a certain range

Tags: c

can any one give me some insight as to how i would go about making a simple program in C that when i enter for instance the number 16( represents the number of factors a certain integer has) the program would count how many values going from 1-100000 that have exactly 16 factors.
I'm just starting with C so please do elaborate and use rather simple methods.

i have done this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
   int n,x=1,y=100000,factors,count;

   printf( the  number of factors:\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   for(factors=0;factors<=1;factors++){ 
     if(x%factors==0&&y%factors==0){
        count++;
     }
   }

   printf("There are %d numbers between 1 and 100000 inclusive which have exactly %d divisors\n",
          n,factors);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587512/counting-positive-integers-with-a-given-number-of-divisors

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that returns the number of factors a number has. Then loop from 1 to 100,000, calling that function. For each return that matches the specified number, increment the count. Then return the count.